# Sublime Text macro to find and replace file path characters on current line

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I use Sublime 2 for developing R and PHP code, although I imagine this shortcut would be useful for other languages.

If I copy the path of a file from Windows Explorer / XYPlorer (or other source) it has backslashes for directories.  When entering a path into the source code, it needs forward slashes.

Sublime has some reasonably powerful macro commands, but I cannot think of a combination that would be able to:

- take the string of text on the current line
- replace all instances of '\' and replace them with '/'

Here is the workflow that I envisage:

1. Locate my filename in Explorer and copy its path
2. In Sublime, write a line of code and paste in the path
3. Hit a keyboard shortcut, say Ctrl+Shift+\, and all back slashes are converted to forward slashes

The result:

```
myPath = "E:\WORK\Code\myFile.csv";
```

Becomes:

```
myPath = "E:/WORK/Code/myFile.csv";
```

Without running the risk of backslashes elsewhere in the file being changed (e.g. \n characters), and without having to use multiple key presses or mouse clicks.

I imagine this would be possible with Regex.  Two things I am no expert in are Sublime macros or regex, so I wonder if anyone else knows the magical commands that would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this for about 15 minutes. A few things:

1. Sublime text 2 doesn't allow for find/replace with macros
2. Sublime text 3 doesn't allow for 'find in selection'

So, I think you are kind of beat right now other than writing a plugin, which would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, that is a shame...  Writing a plugin doesn't look that straightforward to me =S

Comment: Is it possible to edit a macro and add the find command? Here is a list of commands, but I don't know if you can use them to write a macro: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for Sublime Text 3:

Type r before the string to tell python to read the directory as a raw string.
This way all the backslashes are read as slashes instead of 'ignore next character' (default meaning of \ in python)

Example

```
myPath = r"E:\WORK\Code\myFile.csv"
```

Python should now read the \ as /

Answer (score 1):

We don't need Plugins. Here is the sublime text macro code to replace "War" with "Love".

```
[
    {
        "args": {"to": "bof"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args": {"characters": "War"}, "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args": {"extend": true, "to": "bol"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "command": "slurp_find_string"
    },
    {
        "args": {"characters": "Love"}, "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args": {"extend": true, "to": "bol"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "command": "slurp_replace_string"
    },
    {
        "args": null, "command": "left_delete"
    },
    {
        "args": {"close_panel": true }, "command": "replace_all"
    },
]
```